# Using Circuitikz in Beamer

Tags: beamer

I cannot compile a beamer presentation with the circuitikz package.  Does anyone know if it is possible, I get an error:

```
undefined control sequence \usepackage{circuitikz}
```

Below is my code (simplified version)

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{default}

\usepackage{tikz} 
\usepackage{siunitx} 
\usepacakge[siunitx]{circuitikz} 

\begin{document}

  \begin{frame}
    \begin{figure}[!htb]
      \centering
      \begin{circuitikz}[scale = 1.4] \draw
    (0,0) node[anchor=east]{$E_{in} -$} 
      to[short, o-] (4,0) 
      to[V, v=$E_{emf}(t)$] (4,2)
      to[L, l=$L_m$] (3,2)
      to[R, l=$R_m$] (1,2) -- (0,2)
      to[short, o-] (0,2)
      node[anchor=east]{$E_{in} +$};
      \end{circuitikz}
      \caption{Circuit Diagram of Motor}
      \label{fig:basicMotor_wInductor}
    \end{figure}

  \end{frame}


\end{document}
```

I could just copy/ paste the image from my report, but I would prefer to include the code in Beamer.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

it could be that you don't have the latest version of circuitikz....

but before you try to download the newest version try:
**\usepackage[siunitx]{circuitikz}**

Latest version: 
https://code.google.com/p/circuitikz/source/browse/#hg%2Ftex%2Flatex%2Fcircuitikz

Place the files in the same folder as your tex or place the files into your directory...
e.g.: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Packages/Installing_Extra_Packages

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I already had the latest package installed (alongside the older one which came with my Ubuntu package manager).

Answer (score 0):

When I changed \usepacakge[siunitx]{circuitikz} to \usepackage[siunitx]{circuitikz} your code works for me.